# Optimize sum of powers with constant double exponent

Tags: c++, optimization

I have implemented an algorithm which at some point needs to calculate the sum of the powers of the elements of a vector. The power is a positive double which is constant during the loop. I figured out, that this calculation is currently the bottleneck of my program and wonder if there is a way to speed up the following code snippet:

```
double SumOfPowers(std::vector<double>& aVector,double exponent)
{
    double help = 0;
    size_t sizeOfaVector = aVector.size();
    for (size_t k = 0; k < sizeOfaVector; k++)
    {
        help += std::pow(aVector[k], exponent);
    }
    return help;
}
```

I have a feeling as if one could exploit the fact that the exponent is constant during the loop and reduce the expensive std::pow calls. Does anyone know a better way of implementing this, or if there is a ready to use library function that does the job?

Comment: I would firstly check whether the loop is vectorized.

Comment: @Petr: How can I check this?

Comment: how many entries does your vector have?

Comment: @m.s.Typically varries between 1 and about 100

Comment: Either disassemble and check the instructions generated, either use some compiler options. For gcc this is `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2`. And, of course, first switch vectorizing on. For gcc, the simplest way is to set `-O3`.

Comment: I'm using VC 2013. Automatic vectorization is on, but does not seem to have any effect on the performance of this loop. I've checked the difference using #pragma loop(no_vector) in front of the for loop but it does not have any effect. Is supose this is related to the relatively short vectors.

Comment: @PaulR. on which platform/processor are you executing this code? I just [timed summing up 100 random values](https://ideone.com/8Fu4uN) and it took less than 6 microseconds on an Intel i7-4600U. Is this really an issue for you?

Comment: @m.s. The function resides in a nested loop. It is called billions of times during the execution of the whole algorithm.

Comment: Uh oh - another Paul R in the C++ and optimisation tagspace - this could get confusing... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, check whether the loop is vectorized. For this, build your program with `-O3` (here and in what follows I assume gcc compiler; I do not know much about other compilers, but I expect they have similar options). Add also `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2` option to get detailed output on which loops were vectorized. You might want to play around with options to get the output you want.

If the loop was not vectorized, then you can make it vectorized. You might need to change the loop structure (for example, first compute all powers into a separate array, and only then calculate the sum), or use some way to tell some more info to the compiler such as `restrict` declaration, see ["Auto-vectorization with gcc 4.7"](http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/) for more discussion. In the worst case, I think, you can implement vectorization by hand, I remember that there were such functions, see [Intel's reference](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) or ["A practical guide to SSE SIMD with C++"](http://sci.tuomastonteri.fi/programming/sse).

For Visual Studio, start with adding [`/Qvec-report:2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj614596.aspx) option to get verbose reporting. All the other suggestions from above do also apply, you will just need to find corresponding MSVC options.

---

Another way to speed the things up is to sacrifice precision by using `-ffast-math` option. AFAIK, the standard `pow` function uses some advanced logic to check for cases when base or exponent are really close to 1 to avoid precision problems there.  If this is not your case, you might not need that logic. I suppose that `-ffast-math` drops it, although you might want to check it.

Anyway, you can just replace `pow` by `exp(log(...)*...)` to avoid these checks manually. This will not give you much speedup, but you might notice some gain. Also, in case you frequently raise the same vector to different exponents, you can pre-calculate `log`s.

Comment: The suggestion to multiply logs may well be useful if different powers are often needed - in which case, store the logs instead of, or as well as, the plain valuse.

Comment: @Petr I checked the vectorization information output. (In addition to /Qvec-report:2 one also needs to set the warnings at least to level 4 (/W4).) The loop was not vectorized. I’ve changed the code to use a temporary vector to store the powers in and sum them with std::accumulate afterwards. Now the loop is vectorized and I takes 22% less time with sizeOfaVector = 10 and 48 % less time with sizeOfaVector = 100. That's great! I've learned a lot today. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

No, the constant exponent does not allow for a feasible optimization unless your values are frequently repeated (if so: memoize). Parallelize is your best bet here (or do not `pow` at all)

Comment: This function is called inside a parallized loop, so unfortunately, parallizing does not help with this specific problem. Also, the values do not repeat frequently. Maybe I have to face the fact that I am touching the limit of the optimization.