# How to make this color percentage function faster? C++

Tags: c++, math, optimization

```
extern inline double getColorPercentage(uint8_t *pixel, uint8_t *pixel2) {
    //pixel 1 is 255, 255, 255
    //pixel 2 is 0, 0, 0
    //match is 0

    //pixel 1 and 2 is 255, 255, 255
    //match is 1.0
    return (255-fabs(pixel[2] - pixel2[2])) * (255-fabs(pixel[1] - pixel2[1])) * (255-fabs(pixel[0] - pixel2[0])) /16581375.0;
}
```

I wrote this function and tried to optimize it and am hoping it can be optimized further. I'm using it a lot, anyone know of a way to make it more performant?

Comment: Why are you using `fabs()` instead of `abs()`?

Comment: You should use `static inline` instead of `extern inline`.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to Code Review.  That site wasn't one of the choices on the menu though (I wonder why?), and I don't want to flag it as "requiring moderator intervention".  Maybe another user can migrate it?

Comment: @Panzercrisis The best way of action is to vote to close as "too broad" and leave a comment. It is not in the list because a) It has not fully graduated yet (but is scheduled to do so) b) There are still quite a lot of SO users that don't get what's really on-topic on Code Review.

Comment: `pixel1` and `pixel2` should be declared `const uint8_t *`

Comment: Moderator, following advice, I flagged this as "too broad", but that's because I think it belongs on Code Review and couldn't select it on the list of options.  It is asking a somewhat general question of how the code above can be improved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary `int` to `float` conversions going on. Also division by a constant can be converted to multiplication. Here is a potentially more efficient version:

```
inline double getColorPercentage(const uint8_t *pixel, const uint8_t *pixel2)
{
    const double scale = 1.0 / (255.0 * 255.0 * 255.0); // compile-time constant
    int m0 = 255 - abs(pixel[0] - pixel2[0]); // NB: use std::abs rather than fabs
    int m1 = 255 - abs(pixel[1] - pixel2[1]); // and keep all of this part
    int m2 = 255 - abs(pixel[2] - pixel2[2]); // in the integer domain
    int m = m0 * m1 * m2;
    return (double)m * scale;
}
```

As always, you should carefully benchmark and profile the original version and any optimised version, and be aware that optimisations made with one compiler and target platform may not be useful for another.

Comment: Is it just my imagination or do you have the same number of function calls?

Comment: Superficially yes, but `abs` should get inlined.

Comment: Why would `fabs` not be? Especially as, just as for integers, [it's usually as simple as setting the value of a single bit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2878109/560648).

Comment: You're right - a good compiler will also inline `fabs` - I just checked with g++ 4.9.2. I'll retract my comment about function calls and stick with the unnecessary int to float conversions etc.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: unless you are programming on some very old systems, `abs()` on integers is not as simple as setting the value of a single bit.  it can be inlined and compiled to a few instructions without jumps, but is not as straightforward as `fabs()`.  Careful benchmarking only will tell what is faster on a given architecture.

Comment: @chqrlie: Sorry, true. But that only strengthens my argument, in fact.

Comment: I like the answer, but why are the `int` variables being used?

Comment: The temporary variables are just there for clarity/readability and ease of debugging - they will get optimised away by the compiler so they don't have an impact on performance.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: just for clarity.  The compiler, if properly configured, will mush all this into a single blob of assembly code and not use any local stack based temporary variables.

Answer (score 3):

First I would suggest you use [`std::abs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) instead of `std::fabs()` as you are dealing with `uint8_t` which is not a floating point type.  If that still doesn't give you enough performance you can try this:

```
extern inline double getColorPercentage(uint8_t *pixel1, uint8_t *pixel2)
{
    int a = 255 - (pixel1[2] > pixel2[2] ? pixel1[2] - pixel2[2] : pixel2[2] - pixel1[2]);
    int b = 255 - (pixel1[1] > pixel2[1] ? pixel1[1] - pixel2[1] : pixel2[1] - pixel1[1]);
    int c = 255 - (pixel1[0] > pixel2[0] ? pixel1[0] - pixel2[0] : pixel2[0] - pixel1[0]);
    return (a * b * c) / 16581375.0;
}
```

As always make sure you are compiling with optimizations on and in release build.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Little bit of aixelsyd ;)

Comment: This one looks good, but it will be harder for the compiler to get rid of the tests.  I wouldn't be surprised if benchmarking proved it substantially slower on random data than the simplistic `fabs()` version.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answer, you might want to check whether your calculations are vectorized. Please see [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30507794/3216312); I can even imagine that there can be a separate intrinsic just for your case.

In fact, in your particular function the subtraction/multiplication "loop" can be vectorized, but if you call your function from some loop (which I assume you do, otherwise why is it a bottleneck?), then maybe vectorizing the outer loop will prove even more efficient.